# can I retrieve version of file from git for a given date?

Tags: git, date, version

I need to retrieve the version of some file in my git repository which was the last commit before a date. For example, my date is 2013-03-08 and so I want to the version of the file committed on 2013-03-07 or before.

I can use a command like `git show HEAD~<REVISION-NUM>:foo/bar/myfile.c` but I have to figure out what `<REVISION-NUM>` is for my date. Moreover, if I need to retrieve multiple files for the same date, their `<REVISION-NUM>`s might be different.

So is there a command that would allow me to specify the date directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `rev-parse`

`git help rev-parse` for details e.g.

```
git checkout 'master@{2013-06-01}'
git checkout 'master@{yesterday}'
git checkout 'master@{5 days ago}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the most recent commit before the desired date:

```
git log -n1 --before <date>
```

You could then just check out that commit (i.e. `git checkout <sha1>`) and see the state of all files as of that time.